# Load json object from file (Jinja2)

Tags: json, templates, jinja2, jinja2-cli

I have a json file called `values.json` with different atributes:

```
{
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2",
    "key3": "value3"
}
```

Using Jinja2, I am trying to import it and get just `value1`, but i don't find the way of doing it.
I manage to import all the json and print it in a file called `test.j2`:

```
{%- import "./values.json" as values -%}
{{ values}}
```

but I don't know how to get only the value of `key1`. I am trying to convert first the file to json and then get the value:

```
{%- import "./values.json" as values -%}
{% set values_json = values | string | tojson %}
{{ values_json.key1 }}
```

But I get an empty response. Do you know how I should do it?

The command I use to test it is `jinja2 test.j2`

Answer (score 0):

`import` feature is about "Jinja supports putting often used code into macros. These macros can go into different templates and get imported from there" ([more info here](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#import)). Seems it's not about importing a file as a variable.

I can tell you are running jinja2-cli (jinja2 test.j2). From its [documentation](https://github.com/mattrobenolt/jinja2-cli) one option to load a JSON file with variables and passing it to the template is by running:

```
jinja2 test.j2 values.json --format=json
```

and your template will be able to access the key1, key2, key3 variables directly.

**test.j2**:

```
{{ key1 }}
{{ key3 }}
{{ key2 }}
```

**prints**:

```
value1
value3
value2
```